# Spring mvc form validation reports no errors despite @NotNull and @Size annotations

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

I'm learning java and spring. I tried to test form validation from book "Spring in action 4th edition". 
No matter what I input into form field it's always OK for the validator. However it should reject empty or too short text. Validator is downloaded from Hibernate webpage.
 I tried version 4.2 and latest stable 6.1.
Spring is in version 4.3.18.
I use IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate in version 2019.3
As server I use Tomcat 9.0.27.
Here I put some source:

**Controller**:

```
package org.maciek.second;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import javax.validation.Valid;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
public class TestController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String page(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("test",new Test());
        return "test/main";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/process", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String page2(@Valid Test test, Errors errors, Model model) {
        if(errors.hasErrors()) {
            return "test/main";
        }
        System.out.println(test.getVal1());
        return "test/ok";
    }
}
```

**Test** class with val1 entered from web form:

```
package org.maciek.second;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

public class Test {
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min=3, message = "message")
    private String val1;

    public String getVal1() {
        return val1;
    }

    public void setVal1(String val1) {
        this.val1 = val1;
    }
}
```

**Web** .jsp page with simple form:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="sf" %>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<sf:form action="/test/process" commandName="test" method="post">
    <sf:input path="val1"/><sf:errors path="val1"/>
    <input type="submit" value="OK"/>
</sf:form>
</body>
</html>
```

**WebAppInitializer**

```
package org.maciek.second;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {RootConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {WebConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }

}
```

**WebConfig**

```
package org.maciek.second;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("org.maciek.second")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView.class);
        resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

**RootConfig**

```
package org.maciek.second;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan.Filter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.FilterType;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"org.maciek.second"}, excludeFilters = {
        @Filter(type= FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = EnableWebMvc.class)
})
public class RootConfig {

}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like your using Spring Boot (you really should), and I don't see a validator configured anywhere.

Comment: I don't use Spring Boot yet. It's one of the next steps of my spring education. As far as I searched internet and some udemy courses validator should be added somehow automatically. In none of examples I saw nobody configured validator manually.

Comment: Needs more focus: Too many scenarios , Validator not invoked, validator is  invoked  but no errors are displayed and so on.... Can you debug and clarify exactly what happens.

Comment: Boot is not "advanced" Spring, it is _simple_ Spring. Start with it.

Comment: I'm new to spring. I don't know how to check if validator was invoked. What i'm sure is that `errors.hasErrors()` returns false. On console i see that `System.out.println(test.getVal1());` shows right value. Right means the one that was input to the form field , but shouldn't be validated.

Answer (score 1):

I can definitelly say that problem is solved. Problem was with not updated server artifacts in IntelliJ IDEA. Because of this required libraries were not deployed to server. As I said I'm learning so I make mistakes. I'll remember this lesson.